# SQLite - multithread read and write in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite, c++11

I have C++11 app, that uses multiple threads. Each thread can read or write database, eg. doing `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT`.
I have enabled serialized mode for SQLite, so connection can be shared between threads.

However, I dont know, how to run queries. Can I just run single query and create statement via `sqlite3_prepare_v2`? Or, should I add my own locks via `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` and do something like:

```
Thread #1
db.lock()
db.query("....").execute()
db.unlock()

Thread #2
db.lock()
res = db.query("....").select()
while(res) res.row()
db.unlock()
```

Or is there any other way? I have been looking for some sample code, but found nothing.

Comment: I think you don't need mutex. just make two connection and do your query.

Comment: Does db serialize all operations on serverside?

Comment: According to https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_covering_index_scan.html#sqliteconfigserialized, it should serialize connection and statement. However, that does not tell anything about concurency.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik SQLite has no serverside.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6

Comment: @manni66 So according to that, I dont have to take care of anything and just run queries, am I right?

Comment: According to that: _Threads are evil. Avoid them_ and _See the threading mode documentation for additional information_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [*Serialized*](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_covering_index_scan.html#sqliteconfigserialized) mode you don't need manual locking to execute queries. According to the SQLite documentation:

> In this mode (which is the default when SQLite is compiled with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1) the SQLite library will itself serialize access to database connections and prepared statements so that the application is free to use the same database connection or the same prepared statement in different threads at the same time.

You can also consider to use [*WAL*](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) to get more concurrency. In this mode reading and writing can proceed concurrently. Include `journal mode=WAL` in the connection string to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

"Thread-safe" means that *individual* function calls are safe. However, when function calls from multiple threads are interleaved, this does not prevent one thread from modifying data that another thread is currently reading with multiple steps; this can result in nonsensical data.

You have to ensure that multiple threads do not attempt to use the same connection object for different transactions at the same time. Either use your own lock (as shown in the code), or use separate connection objects for each thread.

Comment: Hi CL, could you be a bit more concrete on the example? does that mean that each thread will require a db.open() ?

Comment: How else would you get separate connection objects?